# NoClassDefFoundError: io/github/classgraph/ClassGraph

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, classgraph

Am having jdk 19 and when I try to execute a feature file by giving Run as -> cucumber feature then am getting the below error and same applies with Java 11 as well

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/github/classgraph/ClassGraph

Below is the project file

Maven project named demo

under src/test/java I have created a feature file named test.feature and below is the content

Feature: Get users demo

Background:
Given url 'https://reqres.in/api'

Scenario: Get user success flow

Given path '/users/2'

When method GET

Then status 200

And print response

POM.xml has a dependency related to karate framework

Under Maven dependencies section I could see the classgraph-4.8.149.jar but still thrown with error

I din face any issue when ran with jdk 8 but with java 11 and 19 facing this error . Can I get some help on this please how to resolve this

Comment: check this out - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: I deleted all version of Java from my machine and re-installed java11 and this issue got sorted